# Why is TABLE not POPULATING in V$IM_SEGMENTS even after scanning?

Tags: oracle12c, in-memory-database, in-memory, in-memory-tables

So I have added a table to inmemory and have scanned the table after that. But it is still not appearing in V$IM_SEGMENTS. In EXPLAIN PLAN it is showing INMEMORY ACCESS FULL. So not sure if it is using the column store.

Did these:

ALTER TABLE  INMEMORY;
SELECT * FROM ;

SELECT * FROM V$IM_SEGMENTS;

> no rows

Answer (score 0):

To start with `inmemory_size` should be around [100M](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/inmem/enabling-the-im-column-store.html#GUID-3CC8549A-A394-49CC-A907-AEB471A19CB3). 
Following command should show appropriate size value for parameter `inmemory_size`:

```
show parameter inmemory_size
```

Loading of table segments into inmemory area kicks when there is a full scan on the table or inmemory priority clause is other than `none`, so we need to be sure the select query you had done went through `table access full` path.
So, one more way to initiate full table scan is to do `select count(*) from table`.

Or you can use `populate` procedure from `dbms_inmemory` [package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_INMEMORY.html#GUID-E3DF69A9-0823-4C00-AB3D-98FD1AEC8629) to load the table manually into inmemory area.

Example usage (for user inmem_user, table t1):

```
exec dbms_inmemory.populate('INMEM_USER','T1');
```

One more thing to consider here with respect to querying `v$im_segments` is; `bytes_not_populated` and `populate_status` columns also to be queried for correctness.
When `v$im_segments` returns rows, `bytes_not_populated` should be `0` and `populate_status` should be `COMPLETED`.

More information about inmemory population can be foune [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/inmem/populating-objects-in-memory.html#GUID-C5F856BF-70E3-41C6-A1BA-1E94D7D230B8)